# How do I set microk8s containerd.sock as runtime endpoint for crictl?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, crictl

I want to inspect container images that are running in a microk8s test cluster and don't want to use the in built tooling? And tips on where the container runtime is for microk8s?

Normally when I use kubeadm to deploy a single node cluster it comes with crictl or docker and I'm used to using those tools to inspect the container images, not the case with microk8s

Answer (score 0):

Crictl config is located @ /etc/crictl.yaml

```
sudo vim /etc/crictl.yaml
```

.

```
runtime-endpoint: "unix:///var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock"
image-endpoint: "unix:///var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd.sock"
timeout: 0
debug: false
pull-image-on-create: false
disable-pull-on-run: false
```

Run sudo crictl ps and view your container images

Found containerd sock grepping ps faux

```
ps faux | grep -i microk8s | grep -i sock
```